# Probability of $2$ people leaving their rooms

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, random-variables, independence

$7$ people enter a hotel and go into $4$ rooms numbered $1$ to $4$. Each person chooses
at random a room to go into, independently of other people.

Exactly two people leave their rooms in the first day. What is the probability
that the two people who left the hotel were not from the same room?

How do I start doing this kind of problems? Please help! :(

Update: We are not assuming that each room has to have 1 person in it. We can have empty rooms.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let the first person leave the room $X$. What is the probability that the second person was in the same room?

> The probability is $\frac14$ so that the answer to your question is $1-\frac14=\frac34$. Important is only the fact that people choose the room independently and at random. Also important is the fact that there are at least two people in the hotel. Everything else (e.g. exact number of the people) is irrelevant.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120684/discussion-on-answer-by-user-probability-of-2-people-leaving-their-rooms).